# Sending params with angular's $http to a HttpPost action method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

My serverside (ASP.NET MVC) has this action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonNetResult MyAction(long param1, string param2, string stringifiedJson)
    {
       ...
    }
```

With JQuery I can use this action easily, like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/bla/myAction',
        data: {
            "param1": 123,
            "param2": "blah",
            "stringifiedJson": JSON.stringify(someJSON),
        },
        success: function (data) {
                ...
        }
    });
```

But with angularjs, I haven't been able to do the request. This is what I'm trying:

```
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/bla/myAction",
        params: {
            param1: 123,
            param2: "blah",
            stringifiedJson: JSON.stringify(someJSON)
        },
        data: {
        }
    });

    httpRequest.success(function(response) {

        ...
    });
```

In fact, angularjs isn't even doing a HTTP POST.. it is doing a OPTIONS request so I'm getting 404 not found.

Question is... how can I do a post request with params? I know I could use "data" but then, how do I make ASP.NET MVC to map the request to each method parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The data you are sending should have the same names as the asp.net mvc method parameters.
f.e
if u have method

```
public ActionResult doSomethingMethod(string name, string surname)
{
 //code
}
```

from angularjs:

```
 $http({
  url: "your url",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
      name: "Jon",
      surname: "Doe"
  }
 })
```

there is also quicker way

```
var dataToSend = {name:"Jon",surname:"Doe"};
$http.post("your url",dataToSend);
```